# Error when trying to export a feature in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, export

I'm trying to export a feature/plug-in in Luna, but I get the following error:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-12-09 12:01:30.964 !MESSAGE An
>   internal error occurred during: "Export Features". !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.NativeCodeSpecificationImpl.isSatisfiedBy(NativeCodeSpecificationImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.module.ResolverImpl.isResolvable(ResolverImpl.java:285)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.module.ResolverImpl.resolveBundles(ResolverImpl.java:639)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.module.ResolverImpl.resolve(ResolverImpl.java:477)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateImpl.resolve(StateImpl.java:545)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.StateImpl.resolve(StateImpl.java:605)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.site.BuildTimeSite.getRegistry(BuildTimeSite.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BuildScriptGenerator.generateFeatures(BuildScriptGenerator.java:276)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.BuildScriptGenerator.generate(BuildScriptGenerator.java:127)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:257)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.doExport(FeatureExportOperation.java:224)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.pde.internal.core.exports.FeatureExportOperation.run(FeatureExportOperation.java:108)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

And I have no errors in my plug-in project. When I do this in Kepler, it works fine. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if they is a more complete message.

Comment: this usually happens due to any conflicting features/plugins present in the IDE. Get a fresh Luna installation and check if this is happening there too.

Comment: @UnniKris - I've tried that, but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I've updated Eclipse from version 4.4.0 to 4.4.1 and now it works.